# Lp-norm without using any python library

Tags: python, norm

How do you find Lp-norm without using any python library?

```
def norm(vec, p):
    # p is scalar
    # where vec is a vector in list type
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy for instance would be more efficient, but with bare python you can do:

```
def norm(vec, p):
    return sum([i**p for i in vec])**(1/p)
```